# Get notified when SMS is received on a Web App

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twilio

I'm currently building a web app that receives incoming SMS messages and saves them to a SQL server.  On the users' side, I have a dashboard where they can see all the people that have been messaged or have sent a message to user.  For the sms messaging part I am using Twilio (http://www.twilio.com).  Does anyone know of a way to check for new messages and retrieve them without having to reload the entire page?

Answer (score 1):

If they are already being saved to your database then some basic javascript on your page which is polling your server via ajax every x seconds will do.

Have the server side code check the database and return any new entries then insert them into the page using a promise attached to your ajax call. Save the timestamp and use it next time as the cutoff point for messages to return, rinse and repeat.

Comment: But how would you get all the new database entries from a specific time?

Comment: Have a timestamp column in your database which is set to record value upon insert, then have your javascript submit the timestamp with each request and only return values later than that. Or have the script start running onload and supply the id from the latest row in the database on page load, and only return entries above that id. Pass the latest id each time.

Answer (score 0):

there are (at least) three ways to accomplish real time updates
1. ajax polling
2. push notifications
3. sockets

1. ajax - @miknik has explained this well
2. push notifications - there are several implementations.  one to consider is pusher (https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-notifications)
3. sockets - there are several implementations.  one to consider is ratchet (http://socketo.me/).  laravel + ratchet is a popular option as described here (https://medium.com/@mohyaddinalaoddin/web-sockets-made-easy-with-laravel-and-ratchet-149a0e63a74f).